# Высшак: семантика и этимология

Tags: этимология, семантика

Поиск по точному совпадению "высшак" выдаёт [1440 результатов](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%22).

Простой вопрос: какие у этого слова семантика и этимология?

Answer (score 1):

Высшак, судя по тому, что находится в интернете это мем.

Что такое мем? мем - это слово-идиома или идиома образованная через монтаж смыслов/значений/реакций.

Высш+ак.

Монтаж мог происходить как путем вырезаний, так и путем привнесения нехарактерных слову элементов:

Например: жд+ун - нехарактерный суффикс. Хотя в целом, он может быть - играть-игрун, бодать-бодун, ждать-ждун.

Ну или "ничего себе" - при произнесении редуцируется до "ниче-се-е", а мем будет звучать, например, как "ничёси". А кто-то его еще переделает на что-то между ничеси и анчоусами - получит анчёси. Поэтому есть смысл воспринимать эти слова не через семантику или этимологию, а через юмор, то есть через отрицание какого-либо значения и смысла, обессмысливание слово, вызывающее смех.

То есть мем - это неспецифический монтаж значения или смысла приводящий к утрате смысла или значения слова, ну и вызывающий реакцию смеха. Мемы - это смешно, но не понятно.

Вышак - это жаргонное название, например, раздела высшей математики, то есть **"вышка" или "вышак" - это что-то очень сложное, понятное единицам**, которое скорее произошло от жаргонизма высшая мера наказания - вышка или вышак, потому без С. Однако, тут у нас слово с С. Поэтому его употребляют в шутках, когда хотят подчеркнуть абсурдность фразы:

> Музей истории искусств: Высшак! - просмотрите отзывы путешественников.

Неоправданный пафос.

> Отложил в сторонку, буду подробно изучать))) Доработок тьма! Модель просто высшак!!!))) Как ты делал колечки на замках зипа за комбашней? Я их на макро разглядел с трудом))) Спасибо, Максим!

Обилие смайликов дополнительно указывает на сарказм который хотя разбавить несерьезностью отношения.

> Лучший выбор пива в самаре. Есть чего нет нигде и реально свежее и настоящее. А фирменные яйца замаринованные это высшак!

"Фирменные яйца замаринованные" - что? Высшак! - тогда ясно, хаха.

Как-то так.

Ну и мем - это не слово, а реакция, то как нужно реагировать на слово, поэтому к мему часто прилагается картинка. Однако с картинками к высшак как-то не срослось. Видимо поэтому это вызвало у вас сложность в восприятии данного мема. НУ бывает, это такие "мемы не для всех", специфичное неспецифическое, одним словом - **ВЫСШАК, так умно(пафосно), что не передать словами.**

Добавлю новые мысли про **мемы** и про **монтаж**, видимо не всем это слово знакомо. Почему мем - это монтаж смыслов, что такое монтаж?

Дело в том, что мемы как термин - слово новое, но на самом деле мемы использовать стали давно. Сергей Эйзенштейн, советский(но я бы сказал русский) теоретик кино и режиссер, ввел такое понятие и метод киноискусства ["Монтаж аттракционов"](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD_%D0%9E_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9/2). Когда на зрителя можно воздействовать не через логически выверенное повествование, а через свободный выбор и сочетание уже значений. Например, момент из "Броненосец Потёмкин" с коляской. Тут интересно, что на заре киноискусства это было похоже на прочтение вслух коротких слов или фраз, там четко слышатся слова "женщина кричит! паника! люди бегут! солдаты идут! люди падают с лестницы! люди падают от выстрелов! солдаты стреляют!..." - ну и все заканчивается знаменитой люлькой с младенцем которая тоже катится падая по лестнице, а потом приходи Потёмкин и матросы в белом спасают народ от произвола солдат. Ну и все конечно под соответствующую музыку. Так вот, не каждый кусок этого кино ряда стал мемом, но стали падающая люлька коляска, ну и Броненосец Потёмкин. Эйзенштейн занимался именно созданием мемов. И именно это повествование(или модное слово нарративом) стало "реальным"(почти) историческим фактом.

То есть мемы могут быть бессмысленными, вроде как сейчас, а могут быть весьма влиятельным методом для достижения цели пропаганды:

> свободный монтаж произвольно выбранных, самостоятельных (также и вне данной композиции и сюжетной сценки действующих) воздействий (аттракционов), но с точной установкой на **определенный конечный тематический эффект** — монтаж аттракционов.

Comment: Что значит "через монтаж смыслов"? Странные определения у вас порой.

Comment: @Серж чем странные? вы не знакомы со словом "монтаж"? Почитайте Сергей Эйзенштейн "монтаж аттракционов", там все доходчиво, как и за счет чего достигаются и формируются "новые смысловые значения", через монтаж, что такое вообще монтаж в искусстве. Мемы - суть монтаж, - слово/фраза плюс картинка, вызывающая эмоциональную реакцию, новый этап в методе монтажа, так сказать. Хотя бывают мемы игры слов, типа ничё(у)си - это немного другое, но тоже монтаж.

Comment: @Серж - а, вот я еще что подумал, Эйзенштейн ведь составляющие мема называл гэги. Мем - это именно смонтированный аттракцион, но без идеологии. Но по Эйзенштейну, суть не в самом аттракционе-меме, а в том, как идеология, которая монтируется между гэгами-мемами, достигает бессознательного зрителей. Он мемы использовал как средство для достижения гипнотического эффекта киноискусства. Вот и думайте теперь, кому и для чего нужны мемы, ну помимо смехуечек.

Comment: Думаю, что правильно *помимо смехуечк**ов*** (род. падеж от слова "смехуёчки"). И — думаю, что ответ надо править.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова если вас не затруднит, пожалуйста. Правьте - что хотите.

Comment: Я говорю о том, что можно не нужно придумывать новые и неудачные громоздкие определения. Вот определение из Кембриджского словаря. «Мем — идея, изображение, видео и так далее, которые очень быстро распространяются в интернете»

Comment: @Серж вам не нужно, а мне нужно. Мне приведенное вами определение совсем не нравится, оно ни о чём. Я не такое определение использовать вообще никак. Потому что в сухом остатке, "мемы - это информация, которая быстро распространяется в интернете". Чушь какая-то. Что значит быстро распространяется в интернете? Хотите я дам вам определение мема, схожее на то, которое дал Докинз, но в целом я с ним тоже согласен. Мем - это вирусная информация, которая заражает мозг адресата, и затем мем-вирус, начинает реплицировать сам себя, заставляя зараженного распространять мем дальше.

Comment: @Серж И к идеям мемы уж точно отношения не имеют, хотя англичане склонны дебилизировать греческие слова и называют идеями в принципе любые посылки и концепции. И мем это все-таки монтаж, потому что вирус не в картинке, вирус в эффекте неожиданности, мем - это неожиданность, в этом мемичность. Вот, например, картина крик - это мем? Это неожиданность, ожидаешь нормальное лицо, а тут черти что, в голове возникает состыковка ожидания и увиденного - и как следствие основа для мема. Но из-за того, что это не монтаж, то есть стыковка не внешняя, а внутренняя, то повторить сложнее.

Comment: @Серж А вот мемом это становится, кода эту картину начинают постить тут и там, выпускают серию ужастиков, и еще напоминают, смотрите мол, герой в костюме - это же  картина такая была. То есть это уже референс на основу. Сама основа же еще не мем, а вот референс и внешняя стыковка узнаваемых образов - это уже мем. Внешний монтаж - это мем. Вопрос не в том, что мем быстро распространяется, а в том, почему он быстро распространяется. То есть это как сказать: коты это животные которых бояться мыши. Почему мыши бояться котов? Потому что те их ловят. То есть коты это животные которые ловят мышей.

Comment: @Серж а мем - это информационный вирус, который заражает людей и самореплицируется. А в интернете он быстро распространяется, только потому, что в интернете сверхпроводимость информации, просто у интернета свойство такое, быстро распространять любую информацию. Картинки не зависимо от мемичности распространяются в интернете с одинаковой скоростью. Ладно, думаю вы поняли, что мем - это вообще не то, что вы мне тут определили. Хотя мем - это слово мем и Кембриджский словарь - тоже мем. И вы прислали этот вариант, просто потому что распространили мем, хотя информация совершенно бессодержательная.